# How to Pass View Data to Partial View in Asp.net core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I am to new .NET core using 2.2 version. I am trying to pass data to partial view with following code :

```
 <partial name="_Emplyees" model="@Model.Employees" view-data="@new ViewDataDictionary(ViewData) { { "index", index }}"/>
```

but its giving syntax error. can someone guide how to pass data and use in partial view? Thanks in advance.

Comment: In Core 2.1 through at least 3.1, there are 3 ways to pass view data to a partial view. Use the Partial tag helper's **for**, **model**, or **view-data** attributes. Documentation is at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/partial-tag-helper?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The issue is that you've got double quotes inside the `view-data` attribute. You need to use single quotes around the attribute value.

```
<partial name="_Emplyees" model="Employees" view-data='@new ViewDataDictionary(ViewData) { { "index", index } }'/>
```

Also, `@Model` is superfluous here, so I removed it.

Answer (score 13):

You could pass the ViewData to partial view like below in ASP.Net Core MVC:

1.Model:

```
public class TestModel
{
    public string Employees { get; set; }
}
```

2.View(Create.cshtml):

```
@model TestModel
@{ 
    ViewData["index"] = true;
}
<partial name="_Emplyees" model="@Model" view-data="ViewData" />
```

3.Partial View:

```
<h3>Index: @ViewData["index"]</h3>
@model TestModel

@if ((bool)ViewData["index"])
{
    @Model.Employees
}
else
{
    <input asp-for="Employees" type="number" class="form-control" />
}
```

4.Controller:

```
public IActionResult Create()
{
    var testmodel = new TestModel() { Employees = "aaa" };
    return View(testmodel);
}
```

5.Result:

[image]

Reference:

[How to use view-data pass the data to partial view](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/partial-tag-helper?view=aspnetcore-3.0#view-data)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/partial?view=aspnetcore-3.0#access-data-from-partial-views

Answer (score 1):

See [Partial views in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/partial?view=aspnetcore-3.0)
 and [Partial Tag Helper in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/partial-tag-helper?view=aspnetcore-3.0).

```
<partial name="Shared/_ProductPartial.cshtml" for="Product">

<partial name="_ProductViewDataPartial" for="Product" view-data="ViewData">

@await Html.PartialAsync("_ProductPartial", product)
```

Note:

When a partial view is instantiated, it receives a copy of the
    parent's ViewData dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

As per the documentation, When a partial view is instantiated, it receives a copy of the parent's ViewData dictionary. Updates made to the data within the partial view aren't persisted to the parent view. ViewData changes in a partial view are lost when the partial view returns.

Checkout the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/partial?view=aspnetcore-3.1#access-data-from-partial-views)

For me I have simply created a partial view, accessed it inside another view and used ViewData directly inside it.

~/Views/Shared/_PageTop.cshtml

```
<a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Go Back</a>
<h1>@ViewData["Title"]</h1>
```

~/Views/Create.cshtml

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
}
<partial name="_PageTop" />
```

So without passing anything to partial view _PageTop, I can access parent's Title property directly using @ViewData["Title"].